# Inheriting from controller, overriding save method with different type

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, controller

I have a project that has a 'core' version, and a 'customised' version.
They are separate projects.

'customised' inherits functionality from 'core' and in some case overrides methods.

For example:

I have a user model that looks like this:

```
public class User
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in a separate assembly,

```
public class User : Core.User
{
    public string CustomProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I then have a controller (in my 'core' assembly)

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveUser(User user)
    {
    }
}
```

In my other project, I have a UserController that inherits from Core.UserController:

```
public class UserController : Core.UserController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveUser(Custom.User user)
    {
    }
}
```

Obviously, in my Global.asax I have the controller namespaces mapped

However, when I hit the SaveUser method, I get

> The current request for action SaveUser on controller type
>   UserController is ambiguous between the following action methods

While I understand the problem, is there any way around this?

In a nutshell:

I want to use `Core.UserController` methods *most* of the time, but in this instance, I need to use my `Custom.UserController` SaveUser method (since it takes my `Custom.User` type)

Answer (score 2):

Polymorphism?

```
public class UserController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public virtual ActionResult SaveUser(User user)
    {
    }
}

public class UserController : Core.UserController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public override ActionResult SaveUser(User user)
    {
         var customUser = user as Custom.User;

         if(customUser != null)
         {
             //Your code here ...
         }      
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work... There's no suitable method to override. The SaveUser method on the second UserController takes a different type

Comment: Right but Custom.User "is a" Core.User, so keep same signature and cast where necessary.

Comment: It won't work with Modelbinding as the binder will create an instance of Core.User not an instance of Custom.User

Answer (score 0):

Another possible workaround if the polymorphism solution doesn't work or isn't acceptable, would be to either rename your UserController or its action method to something slightly different:

```
public class CustomUserController : Core.UserController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveUser(Custom.User user)
    {
    }
}

public class UserController : Core.UserController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveCustomUser(Custom.User user)
    {
    }
}
```

If you wanted to keep the routes consistent with the other project, you would just have to create a custom route for this.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem in my own project today and came across your post.

In my case, while I didn't want to alter the way the core controller's *logic* functioned, I was able to make changes to its code, and thus its modifier keywords. After adding `virtual` to the base controller's actions, and `override` to my derived controller's actions. The original controller's actions still function, my derived controller uses my customized actions, no more ambiguous errors.

I realize you may not be able to modify your Core controller, and if this is the case, then you need to differentiate your actions using some other means. Action name, parameters or some other solution such as a custom implementation of `ActionMethodSelectorAttribute`. That was my first attempt at this problem, but before I got too far down that path of how to implement it, I discovered the virtual/override solution. So I don't have code to share on that route unfortunately.